# How to save models in MLFlow with R and get Stages of them in Azure Databricks?

Tags: python, r, model, azure-databricks, mlflow

I would like to save a model in MLFlow with Azure Databricks. In Python, I can use the following code to save a model with a name automatically:

```py
mlflow.spark.log_model(
        model,
        artifact_path = 'model_prueba',
        registered_model_name = 'model_prueba'
    )
```

[image: Registered models window]

But I am trying to do the same with **R** with the following code:

```r
mlflow_log_model(
          model,
          artifact_path = 'model_prueba_R',
          registered_model_name = 'model_prueba_R'
    )
```

But it does not register any model in the Models section. It only saves the model with the artifact path in the run section.

[image: Artifact location]

Anyone could tell me the way to save the model for staging automatically with code in R?

Thank you very much!